# How to add DOM elements on 360 video

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, video

I am trying to find a way to insert DOM elements over a 360 video so that they will move as the user pans the video. An example of what I am trying to accomplish is found on [this website](https://artsandculture.withgoogle.com/en-us/national-parks-service/parks).If anyone can point me in the right direction or has any suggestion for how to continue I would greatly appreciate it.